# parrot os kde window line problem how to remove it

Tags: kde

how to remove this window line on parrot[image]

last file to configured on my laptop is kwinrc

Comment: i do not see a "window line" in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy paste this default code to kwinrc

[Compositing]
AnimationSpeed=1
Backend=OpenGL
Enabled=true
GLCore=false
GLPreferBufferSwap=a
GLTextureFilter=1
HiddenPreviews=5
OpenGLIsUnsafe=false
WindowsBlockCompositing=true
XRenderSmoothScale=false

[Desktops]
Id_1=2a6f2e5b-cab7-4fbe-9d21-10d5e62f5b3b
Id_2=5290f1f7-f72d-4729-be3f-8476431a2d2c
Id_3=f76cb48d-ceb4-47c0-83bd-929aebb830de
Id_4=31de3aaa-9bd9-4f17-806e-4d1fec4b27d7
Number=4
Rows=1

[Effect-Cube]
BorderActivate=9
BorderActivateCylinder=9
BorderActivateSphere=9

[Effect-DesktopGrid]
BorderActivate=9

[Effect-PresentWindows]
BorderActivate=9
BorderActivateAll=9
BorderActivateClass=9

[ElectricBorders]
Bottom=None
BottomLeft=ApplicationLauncher
BottomRight=None
Left=None
Right=None
Top=None
TopLeft=None
TopRight=None

[Plugins]
blurEnabled=true
contrastEnabled=true
desktopchangeosdEnabled=false
desktopgridEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_fadeEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_fadedesktopEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_fadingpopupsEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_frozenappEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_loginEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_logoutEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_maximizeEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_morphingpopupsEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_squashEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_windowapertureEnabled=false
presentwindowsEnabled=false
screenedgeEnabled=false
slideEnabled=false
slidingpopupsEnabled=false
zoomEnabled=false

[Script-desktopchangeosd]
PopupHideDelay=1000
TextOnly=false

[TabBox]
BorderActivate=9
BorderAlternativeActivate=9
DesktopLayout=org.kde.breeze.desktop
DesktopListLayout=org.kde.breeze.desktop
LayoutName=org.kde.breeze.desktop

[Windows]
ElectricBorderCooldown=350
ElectricBorderCornerRatio=0.25
ElectricBorderDelay=150
ElectricBorderMaximize=true
ElectricBorderTiling=true
ElectricBorders=0
RollOverDesktops=true

[org.kde.kdecoration2]
BorderSize=None
BorderSizeAuto=false
ButtonsOnLeft=MSNH
ButtonsOnRight=FLIAX
CloseOnDoubleClickOnMenu=false
library=org.kde.breeze